# How to retrieve an AJAX data variable to a PHP class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This the AJAX request and I want to access the `latlngArray` in `class-listeo-core-searchphp` which is a PHP class.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'../wp-content/plugins/listeo-core/includes/class-listeo-core-search.php',
    data: {latlngArray:latlngArray},
    success:function(){
    console.log("Success");
 })
```

Comment: this is not how you use ajax in wordpress, check here for more info
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: But I have written this code in map.js file is it still worg?